# Laravel 8: Url Intended Not Working With Custom Login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Into my project I want that the admin who will login will get back to the previous url that the admin has left off while logging out of the admin panel, for login I have used the process that is being described here in https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users but it is not working as i do want, I am pasting my codes below what I have used till now.

```
public function login(Request $request){

        if($request->isMethod('post')){


            
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
                'email'=>'required|email',
                'password'=>'required',
            ],[
                'email.required'=>'Please enter your email address.',
                'password.required'=>'Please enter your password.',
            ]);

            
            if(!$validator->fails()){
                
                

                $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
                if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                    $request->session()->regenerate();
                    return redirect()->intended('admin/dashboard');
                }else{
                    Session::flash('error','Invalid email or password');
                    return redirect()->back();
                }

            }else{
                return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
            }

        

        }

        if($request->isMethod('get')){

            if(!Auth::check()){
                return view('admin.admin_login');
            }else{
                return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
                
            }

        }



    }
```

Routes File

```
Route::prefix('/admin')->group(function(){

    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', [LoginController::class, 'login']);

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin','prevent-back-history']], function () {
        Route::get('/dashboard', function () { return view('admin.dashboard'); })->name('home');
        Route::get('/logout',[LoginController::class, 'logout']);
        Route::get('/roles/status/{id}',[RoleController::class, 'status']);
        Route::resource('roles', RoleController::class);
        Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you post your routes/web.php file too. Looks like you are trying to handle post and get in the same action. You might not have Route::post and Route::get set up correctly

Comment: @Brett Okay I am posting my routes file too

Comment: @Brett You can check I Have updated my post

Comment: Where is it redirecting to on successful login?

Comment: What middleware is responsible for redirecting them if they are not logged in as admin?

Comment: @Brett Going back to the admin dashbord

Comment: @Brett Admin Middleware

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241320/discussion-between-brett-and-baby-babai).

Comment: @Brett Okay Lets do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in chat, what you're after cannot be done. Intended is not for returning someone who logged out long ago back to the same page they were on prior.

It's only useful for returning users back to the page they were accessing when the system found them logged out.

If they clicked log out and then next week arrived back to the site and logged in, it will not redirect them back to that page.

I would suggest storing the value when they log out against the users table if you wanted to achieve this.

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $previous = url()->previous('admin/dashboard');
        
        $request->user()->previous = $previous;
        $request->user()->save();

        $this->guard()->logout();
        //Usual logout code here
```

Then on login action you'd check if the user has that value in the column and redirect to it

```
if ($user->previous) {
    $redirect = $user->previous;
    $user->previous = null;
    $user->save();

    return redirect($redirect);
}
// Otherwise do the usual stuff
```

Create the DB Column with a new migration

```
Schema::table('users', function() {
    $table->string('previous')->nullable()->after('password');
}
```